# Change categoric variable to a dumy matrix in r

Tags: r, variables

I like to use `randomforest` in R, but i get a category with more than 100 levels, so, i can't use randomforest directly.
I like to change the variable with the categories into a matrix with binary values (con column for category an values true/false).
Is there any function to do this directly?

```
Original column
1
2
3
4
4

Target columns
1  2  3  4  
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1
0  0  0  1
```

Kind regards.

Comment: @李哲源 Have you tested it?

Comment: @李哲源 OK, I have now tested it with a factor and your suggestion does work. I should have read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `table`

```
table(seq_along(v1), v1)
```

It does work even if it is an integer/numeric column

#### data

```
v1 <- <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4)
```

Comment: Finaly I has been solved with the library caret like this: library(caret)
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = <data_source>)
<data_target> <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = <data_target>))